# How can I return the entire result set from this NSXMLParser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

This parser only returns one set of values from the result. I have identified the endText method as one that actually extracts the value. 
Any help in understanding this code would be appreciated. Thank you. To be clear, this code is querying Microsoft's Bing Translate API and is from this github project: gpolak/FGTranslator

```
    @interface XMLDictionaryParser () <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *root;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *stack;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *text;

@end


@implementation XMLDictionaryParser

+ (XMLDictionaryParser *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static XMLDictionaryParser *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{

        sharedInstance = [[XMLDictionaryParser alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        _collapseTextNodes = YES;
        _stripEmptyNodes = YES;
        _trimWhiteSpace = YES;
        _alwaysUseArrays = NO;
        _preserveComments = NO;
        _wrapRootNode = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    XMLDictionaryParser *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    copy.collapseTextNodes = _collapseTextNodes;
    copy.stripEmptyNodes = _stripEmptyNodes;
    copy.trimWhiteSpace = _trimWhiteSpace;
    copy.alwaysUseArrays = _alwaysUseArrays;
    copy.preserveComments = _preserveComments;
    copy.attributesMode = _attributesMode;
    copy.nodeNameMode = _nodeNameMode;
    copy.wrapRootNode = _wrapRootNode;
    return copy;
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithParser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    id result = _root;
    _root = nil;
    _stack = nil;
    _text = nil;
    return result;
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    return [self dictionaryWithParser:parser];
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [self dictionaryWithData:data];
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithFile:(NSString *)path
{   
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return [self dictionaryWithData:data];
}

+ (NSString *)XMLStringForNode:(id)node withNodeName:(NSString *)nodeName
{   
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSMutableArray *nodes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[node count]];
        for (id individualNode in node)
        {
            [nodes addObject:[self XMLStringForNode:individualNode withNodeName:nodeName]];
        }
        return [nodes componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    }
    else if ([node isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [(NSDictionary *)node attributes];
        NSMutableString *attributeString = [NSMutableString string];
        for (NSString *key in [attributes allKeys])
        {
            [attributeString appendFormat:@" %@=\"%@\"", [[key description] XMLEncodedString], [[attributes[key] description] XMLEncodedString]];
        }

        NSString *innerXML = [node innerXML];
        if ([innerXML length])
        {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%1$@%2$@>%3$@</%1$@>", nodeName, attributeString, innerXML];
        }
        else
        {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@%@/>", nodeName, attributeString];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%1$@>%2$@</%1$@>", nodeName, [[node description] XMLEncodedString]];
    }
}

- (void)endText
{
    if (_trimWhiteSpace)
    {
        _text = [[_text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
    }
    if ([_text length])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
        id existing = top[XMLDictionaryTextKey];
        if ([existing isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [existing addObject:_text];
        }
        else if (existing)
        {
            top[XMLDictionaryTextKey] = [@[existing, _text] mutableCopy];
        }
        else
        {
            top[XMLDictionaryTextKey] = _text;
        }
    }
    _text = nil;
}

- (void)addText:(NSString *)text
{   
    if (!_text)
    {
        _text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:text];
    }
    else
    {
        [_text appendString:text];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(__unused NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(__unused NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{   
    [self endText];

    NSMutableDictionary *node = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    switch (_nodeNameMode)
    {
        case XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeRootOnly:
        {
            if (!_root)
            {
                node[XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey] = elementName;
            }
            break;
        }
        case XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeAlways:
        {
            node[XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey] = elementName;
            break;
        }
        case XMLDictionaryNodeNameModeNever:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ([attributeDict count])
    {
        switch (_attributesMode)
        {
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModePrefixed:
            {
                for (NSString *key in [attributeDict allKeys])
                {
                    node[[XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix stringByAppendingString:key]] = attributeDict[key];
                }
                break;
            }
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModeDictionary:
            {
                node[XMLDictionaryAttributesKey] = attributeDict;
                break;
            }
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModeUnprefixed:
            {
                [node addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
                break;
            }
            case XMLDictionaryAttributesModeDiscard:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!_root)
    {
        _root = node;
        _stack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:node];
        if (_wrapRootNode)
        {
            _root = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_root forKey:elementName];
            [_stack insertObject:_root atIndex:0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
        id existing = top[elementName];
        if ([existing isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [existing addObject:node];
        }
        else if (existing)
        {
            top[elementName] = [@[existing, node] mutableCopy];
        }
        else if (_alwaysUseArrays)
        {
            top[elementName] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:node];
        }
        else
        {
            top[elementName] = node;
        }
        [_stack addObject:node];
    }
}

- (NSString *)nameForNode:(NSDictionary *)node inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    if (node.nodeName)
    {
        return node.nodeName;
    }
    else
    {
        for (NSString *name in dict)
        {
            id object = dict[name];
            if (object == node)
            {
                return name;
            }
            else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [object containsObject:node])
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(__unused NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(__unused NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(__unused NSString *)qName
{   
    [self endText];

    NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
    [_stack removeLastObject];

    if (!top.attributes && !top.childNodes && !top.comments)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *newTop = [_stack lastObject];
        NSString *nodeName = [self nameForNode:top inDictionary:newTop];
        if (nodeName)
        {
            id parentNode = newTop[nodeName];
            if (top.innerText && _collapseTextNodes)
            {
                if ([parentNode isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                {
                    parentNode[[parentNode count] - 1] = top.innerText;
                }
                else
                {
                    newTop[nodeName] = top.innerText;
                }
            }
            else if (!top.innerText && _stripEmptyNodes)
            {
                if ([parentNode isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                {
                    [parentNode removeLastObject];
                }
                else
                {
                    [newTop removeObjectForKey:nodeName];
                }
            }
            else if (!top.innerText && !_collapseTextNodes && !_stripEmptyNodes)
            {
                top[XMLDictionaryTextKey] = @"";
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [self addText:string];
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    [self addText:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundComment:(NSString *)comment
{
    if (_preserveComments)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *top = [_stack lastObject];
        NSMutableArray *comments = top[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey];
        if (!comments)
        {
            comments = [@[comment] mutableCopy];
            top[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey] = comments;
        }
        else
        {
            [comments addObject:comment];
        }
    }
}

@end


@implementation NSDictionary(XMLDictionary)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLParser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    return [[[XMLDictionaryParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithParser:parser];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLData:(NSData *)data
{
    return [[[XMLDictionaryParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithData:data];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [[[XMLDictionaryParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithString:string];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithXMLFile:(NSString *)path
{
    return [[[XMLDictionaryParser sharedInstance] copy] dictionaryWithFile:path];
}

- (NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = self[XMLDictionaryAttributesKey];
    if (attributes)
    {
        return [attributes count]? attributes: nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *filteredDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self];
        [filteredDict removeObjectsForKeys:@[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey, XMLDictionaryTextKey, XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey]];
        for (NSString *key in [filteredDict allKeys])
        {
            [filteredDict removeObjectForKey:key];
            if ([key hasPrefix:XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix])
            {
                filteredDict[[key substringFromIndex:[XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix length]]] = self[key];
            }
        }
        return [filteredDict count]? filteredDict: nil;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSDictionary *)childNodes
{   
    NSMutableDictionary *filteredDict = [self mutableCopy];
    [filteredDict removeObjectsForKeys:@[XMLDictionaryAttributesKey, XMLDictionaryCommentsKey, XMLDictionaryTextKey, XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey]];
    for (NSString *key in [filteredDict allKeys])
    {
        if ([key hasPrefix:XMLDictionaryAttributePrefix])
        {
            [filteredDict removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    }
    return [filteredDict count]? filteredDict: nil;
}

- (NSArray *)comments
{
    return self[XMLDictionaryCommentsKey];
}

- (NSString *)nodeName
{
    return self[XMLDictionaryNodeNameKey];
}

- (id)innerText
{   
    id text = self[XMLDictionaryTextKey];
    if ([text isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        return [text componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    }
    else
    {
        return text;
    }
}

- (NSString *)innerXML
{   
    NSMutableArray *nodes = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *comment in [self comments])
    {
        [nodes addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!--%@-->", [comment XMLEncodedString]]];
    }

    NSDictionary *childNodes = [self childNodes];
    for (NSString *key in childNodes)
    {
        [nodes addObject:[XMLDictionaryParser XMLStringForNode:childNodes[key] withNodeName:key]];
    }

    NSString *text = [self innerText];
    if (text)
    {
        [nodes addObject:[text XMLEncodedString]];
    }

    return [nodes componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}

- (NSString *)XMLString
{
    if ([self count] == 1 && ![self nodeName])
    {
        //ignore outermost dictionary
        return [self innerXML];
    }
    else
    {
        return [XMLDictionaryParser XMLStringForNode:self withNodeName:[self nodeName] ?: @"root"];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)arrayValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    id value = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    if (value && ![value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        return @[value];
    }
    return value;
}

- (NSString *)stringValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    id value = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        value = [value count]? value[0]: nil;
    }
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        return [(NSDictionary *)value innerText];
    }
    return value;
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    id value = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        value = [value count]? value[0]: nil;
    }
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        return @{XMLDictionaryTextKey: value};
    }
    return value;
}

@end


@implementation NSString (XMLDictionary)

- (NSString *)XMLEncodedString
{   
    return [[[[[self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"]
              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"]
             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"&apos;"];
}

@end
```